# How should we know if our regression have enough power?

Tags: regression, statistical-power

I believe my question is very basic. I was presenting my work in a seminar explaining that my coefficients are not significant. A professor objected, saying that might be due to the low power of my regression. What is a convincing response to such a question?

Generally, suppose that I have a sample size of n (which I am not able to increase) and aim to estimate m parameters. I run a simple OLS, and some of the coefficients turn out to be statistically insignificant. By just looking at the regression table, how can I argue whether I have enough power or not? What are the signs and symptoms of an underpowered analysis?

As I am testing H0:b=0 against H1:b!=0, and thus my H1 is not equality but rather simply the negation of H0, then even conceptually, I think the power cannot be calculated unless we assign a particular value to H1.

Comment: The width of the confidence intervals about the coefficients is one way to go.

Comment: @mdewey essentially this means how big standard errors are. But, what's the reference point? when do we say the standard error is large?

Answer (score 1):

You never have enough power, if you have non-significant results.

To misquote Cohen (1992) from the book "Statistical Power Analaysis": All (non-trivial) null hypotheses are false, at least in their two tailed form."

This is a problem with hypothesis testing. Failing to find a significant effect does not mean that there's no effect. It just means that you didn't find one. A non-significant result is (fairly) uninformative, but people treat it as if it is informative. A significant result is also not informative - it tells you that the null hypothesis is unlikely to be true. But you already know that all (non-trivial) null hypotheses are unlikely to be true.

If you have large effects that are not statistically significant, you probably want to have more power.

Comment: "You never have enough power, if you have non-significant results." I don't agree with this. Power is calculated before you run your experiment. It doesn't depend on the results you observe. You can have an experiment with 90% power at $\theta_0$, the true parameter is $\theta_0$, and you fail to reject the null.

Comment: @Eli I believe it is important to distinguish between the _a priori_ and _post hoc_ powers of a test, the latter of which is what I believe what Jeremy alludes to. One can always use the calculated _post hoc_ power to inform their specification of the _a priori_ power in the hypothetical next experiment.

Comment: @Eil - is 90% enough power? If your result isn't statistically significant, is it one of the 10% that you missed (in which case you didn't have enough power, or is the true effect smaller than you expected (in which case you didn't have enough power.)

Comment: Your comment doesn’t make sense to me. A test with 90% power will fail to reject the null 10% of the time. The power is a property of the test, not the data. The test still has 90% power at $\theta_{H1}$ even if you fail to reject the null. Are you referring to post hoc observed power?

Comment: @JeremyMiles I understand that finding (and for that matter, failing to find) a significant effect doesn't give us certainty (after all, it's statistics). Indeed, the p-value and the power of the test indicate this fact. However, I can design my test to have the desired power (I believe this is at least doable as long as my H1 is equality), and as a researcher, I might be happy with that amount of power.  So why do you say "you never have enough power"?
That aside, my question is about how to learn about the power (of a test H0:b=1 against b!=0) when facing a regression table.

Comment: Is there a circumstance where more power wouldn't be a good thing? Power and statistical significance are a lot more complex than they seem at first (IMHO).